# blueimp file upload - uploads previous selected files

Tags: javascript, file, upload, blueimp

I have this implemented to so it should upload one file at a time. So the user selects a file, clicks upload and then moves on to the next file.

But what the system seems to do is to store the previously selected files and so when the user hits the upload button it sends multiple requests.

I've made sure there is no "multiple" in the html file input box and changed name="files[]" to name="files".

singleFileUploads is set to true

is there a way to reset the file "array" so only one file is stored at a time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? This problem is driving me insane!

Comment: @Andrew  No, I don't think so (just looking at the site it was related too). I think we went with a single file upload.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it anyways :) Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I was also going through the same problem hope the link below helps you in this

[Delete files programatically with jquery fileupload basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044168/delete-files-programatically-with-jquery-fileupload-basic)